# Using Room's @ForeignKey as @Entity parameter in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room, java-annotations

I came across a Room [tutorial](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-room-relationships-bf473510c14a) that makes use of the `@PrimaryKey` annotation on the class definition:

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = User.class,
                              parentColumns = "id",
                              childColumns = "userId",
                              onDelete = CASCADE))
public class Repo {
    ...
}
```

Now, I have the following data class that want to use a primary key on:

```
@Parcel(Parcel.Serialization.BEAN) 
data class Foo @ParcelConstructor constructor(var stringOne: String,
                                              var stringTwo: String,
                                              var stringThree: String): BaseFoo() {

    ...
}
```

So, I just added the `@Entity(tableName = "Foo", foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Bar::class, parentColumns = "someCol", childColumns = "someOtherCol", onDelete = CASCADE))` snippet on the top as well, but I can't compile:

> An annotation can't be used as the annotations argument.

I wonder: how come *(what I think is)* the same concept working in Java but not in Kotlin? Also, is there a way to go around this?

All input is welcome.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

This is the way to provide the annotation you're looking for, with explicit arrays for the arguments, and no `@` for the nested annotation's creation:

```
@Entity(tableName = "Foo", 
    foreignKeys = arrayOf(
            ForeignKey(entity = Bar::class, 
                    parentColumns = arrayOf("someCol"), 
                    childColumns = arrayOf("someOtherCol"), 
                    onDelete = CASCADE)))
```

Since [Kotlin 1.2](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#array-literals-in-annotations), you can also use array literals:

```
@Entity(tableName = "Foo",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(entity = Bar::class,
                parentColumns = ["someCol"],
                childColumns = ["someOtherCol"],
                onDelete = CASCADE)])
```

Comment: someCol is part of class for your example Foo and someOtherCol is for xlass BAr ?

Comment: Actually, the other way around. The child columns are the ones from the current entity (so `Foo` in this case), and the parent columns are from the other entity (`Bar` in this case).